# Check if property has the same value in JSON

Tags: php, json

Given the following json, how can I check if shipmentWay property have the same value for each parent element?

```
{
   "3":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":3,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      }
   ],
   "4":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":3000
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"A\u00e9reo",
         "qty":1500
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":1000
      }
   ],
   "5":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":5,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":5,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm really stuck with this right now, thanks in advance!

Comment: would be easier if you didn't post a screenshot of the json but rather then actual text

Comment: since retyping the screenshot is becoming a pain all i can suggest is looking at [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn it into an object

Comment: @Memor-X you're right. This is my first question in SO. I've updated my question with json string.

Comment: I don't understand.  Which values are you trying to compare?

Comment: @LinneaHuxford I'm trying to compare shipmentWay value for "3","4" and "5" element in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = '{
   "3":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":3,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      }
   ],
   "4":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":3000
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"A\u00e9reo",
         "qty":1500
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":1000
      }
   ],
   "5":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":5,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":5,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      }
   ]
}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$shipmentWay = array();
foreach($array as $key => $parent)
{
  foreach($parent as $index => $child)
  $shipmentWay[$key][$child['shipmentWay']] = true; 
}
//    var_dump($shipmentWay);
    $result = array();
    foreach($shipmentWay as $key => $value)
    {
      $result[$key] = (count($value) > 1)?false:true;
    }
    var_dump($result);
```

demo refer to https://eval.in/667231

the output is

> array(3) {   [3]=>   bool(true)   [4]=>   bool(false)   [5]=>
>   bool(true) }

Comment: I'm getting Notice: Undefined index: shipmentWay

Comment: @Memor-X I've edit it and add the demo, you can check it not.

Comment: @user3720752 Glad it helps, your acception will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok i created [this example](https://repl.it/EHVl/3)

```
function jsonAllSame($jsonStr)
{
    $object = json_decode($jsonStr);

    foreach($object as $objArr)
    {
        $index = 0;
        $compare = "";
        foreach($objArr as $obj)
        {
            if($compare == "")
            {
                $compare = $obj->shipmentWay;
            }
            else
            {
                if($obj->shipmentWay != $compare)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

$json = '{
   "3":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":3,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      }
   ],
   "4":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":3000
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"A\u00e9reo",
         "qty":1500
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":4,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":1000
      }
   ],
   "5":[
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":5,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      },
      {
         "idOrdenCompraProducto":5,
         "shipmentWay":"Confirmation Pending",
         "qty":25000
      }
   ]
}';
$compare = "Confirmation Pending";

var_dump(jSonAllSame($json));
```

the main thing you want to look at is the function `jSonAllSame`. what it does is it takes the json string as an argument. inside the function we decode it then loop though each array of objects that it creates using 2 foreach loops.

the first time we go though the array of objects (second foreach loop) it we have nothing to compare so we set `$compare` to be the first value we see.

in the second iteration since `$compare` is not empty we can do our compare. if we find one value which doesn't match then we stop the function there and return false, if we are able to go though each array of objects and not find a mismatch then we return true.

if we instead wanted to return which array had the first mismatch, assuming that the numbers match the values of `idOrdenCompraProducto` then we replace out `return false;` as `return $obj->idOrdenCompraProducto;`

Comment: Thank you @memor-x  ended with solution below